# Can't connect to EC2 Instance via Browser. Via terminal works fine

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, confluence, connection-refused

I launched an EC2 instance on Amazon Web Services and want to deploy Confluence on a Ubuntu 18.04 Server. Almost everything is set up now. 
I just need the last step: 
I need to call `http://{ec2-public-ip}:8090` from my browser to do the last steps of configuration of Confluence via the frontend, as described in the instructions of Confluence (https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/installing-confluence-on-linux-143556824.html).

I don't have any issues with connecting to the EC2 instance via ssh in terminal (macOS) as ubuntu and also as root by using `privateKey.pem`. This works fine. Installation of Confluence and setting up a MySql DB were also successful. EC2 instance is running. Getting a connection via AWS Session Manager also works, but opens a terminal in my browser and if I ping the EC2 instance via the AWS Session Manager, **there is a 100% packet loss**. Via local terminal **on my mac there is 0% packet loss**.

Also calling `http://{ec2-public-ip}:8090` via browser causes `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` in Safari, Chrome, IE and Firefox.

**What I already tried:**

1. Security Groups (All Traffic, MyIP); also tried to allow Any Traffic
2. Firewall completely off; Proxy completely off
3. Opened all necessary Ports in my Network (8090, 8000, 22, 23)
4. Emptied Browser Cache
5. Flushed DNS; new IP; rebooted router; rebooted EC2 instance

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this problem? I know that there have been a few discussion about this topic, but none of those comments or solutions worked.

Comment: Have you validated the service is running?

Comment: I think I actually did so with sudo /etc/init.d/confluence start. Does not cause any bad notification

Comment: Can you access on local host?

Comment: No. http://localhost:8090/ causes same error.

Comment: Sounds like the problems is the service then, check it’s status and review any app logs

Comment: I can see that the Confluence Service is running and the ec2 instance also.. I think there is a issue with the private key, because if I connect to the instance via ssh in Terminal I‘m giving the instance the path to my private key. When I try to connect via browser the ec2 instance can’t identify me because there is no private key given. I think that either the missing private key or something else in the network connection is blocking.

Answer (score 0):

I chose a different Port as selected by Confluence. This worked immediately. 
The packet loss was caused by the already assigned HTTP Port 80, although Confluence uses 8090 by default. When I pinged the server, all of my packets have been delivered, while all incoming packets went to a different device in my Network. As result my Terminal told me, that no packet was delivered to my Mac. Which was obviously true.

Now everything is up and running just fine.

I saw that a lot of people in the Internet had the same problem. Just try it again but choose different Ports while installing Confluence on your Server.